# error : tools:node associated with an element type uses permission

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, mobile-application

[error is shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAcNH.png)This is my Android manifest file  i am trying to add facebook in my app for login purpose tried to add the required parameter's for facebook login in AndroidManifest.xml file provided in facebook developer docs and got a error below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutter_dami">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
    
        
   <application
        android:label="Daami Music"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
              <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
              <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
              
            <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges=
                        "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Where is error log?

Comment: i have uploaded the screen short  the of error

Answer (score 0):

Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in manifest tag.

Like this,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

When you have to use `tools:node` then you have add that line.

For more info, read : https://developer.android.com/build/manage-manifests#merge_rule_markers